# Applying CSS to the Child component is not working

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, ionic3

I have an inner component as shown below(i.e. `presentation`) .

*edit-playlist.html*

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-3>
              Delete
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
              <presentation [data]="d"></presentation>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-3>
              Text desc
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
```

*edit-playlist.scss* (Here I have tried to override the child's `CSS` within parent)

```
page-edit-playlist {
    .content {
        presentation .presentation .span-icon {
            right: calc(100%-55%);
        }
    }
}
```

*presentation.html*

```
<div class="presentation">
    <span class="span-icon"><ion-icon [name]="data.icon"></ion-icon></span>
    <span class="bottom-text">{{data.text}}</span>
    <img [src]="data.imageUrl" [alt]="data.text" />
</div>
```

*presentaion.scss* (Child `CSS`)

```
presentation {
    .presentation {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .presentation .span-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: calc(100% - 96%);
        color: #fff;
    }
    .presentation .bottom-text {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 16px;
        right: calc(100% - 94%);
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

I need to apply `presentation .presentation .span-icon` to the child component.But you can see that it doesn't apply.Can you tell me how to do that?

[image]

**Note:** But if I add it inside the browser under the `element.style` then it works.So can you tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a space in between the operator and operand like this
`right: calc(100% - 55%);`    to work it properly.

**Clue:** Browser error: `Invalid property value`